# can't load pdfurl to another activity

Tags: java, android, pdf, nullpointerexception, key

I am making an application which load pdf file from storage from internal storage to main activity in my app in list view and try to open pdf file to another activity.

In main activity.java I creating code to load pdf url to PDFWatch activity:
`

```
public ArrayList<File> findPdf (File file){
    ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] files = file.listFiles();

    for (File singleFile: files){
        if (singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()){
            arrayList.addAll(findPdf(singleFile));
        }
        else {
            if (singleFile.getName().endsWith(".pdf")){
                arrayList.add(singleFile);
            }
        }
    }
    return arrayList;




}

public void displayPdf(){
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
    pdfList = new ArrayList<>();
    pdfList.addAll(findPdf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
    adapter = new MainAdapter(this,pdfList,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onPdfSelected(File file) {
    

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PDFwatch.class);

    intent.putExtra("path",file.getAbsoluteFile());

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

in PDFWatch activity.java I wrote below code:

`

```
read = findViewById(R.id.read);

filePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");

File file = new File(filePath);
Uri path  = Uri.fromFile(file);
read.fromUri(path).load();
```

When I click pdf listview to load data. Then Crash display as below:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
        at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:183)
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:130)
        at com.tonyapps.pdfview.PDFwatch.onCreate(PDFwatch.java:27)
```

I thought error happen in PDFWatch.java at line 27.

line 27 in PDFWatch.java is:

`File file = new File(filePath);

I try to solve this issue many days but I don't know how to do. Please Help me solve this problem. Thanks a lot`

I tried to load PDF file from main activity to another activity by using  url. but my app crash and I don't know how to fix

Answer (score 0):

`file.getAbsoluteFile()` returns a `File` object, not a `String` object. Either switch to `file.getAbsolutePath()` or use `getSerializableExtra()` instead of `getStringExtra()`.

Comment: Thanks for your guide. I repair as your comment and it worked. God bless you.